# Laravel Mongodb - Can't get the data from the collection

Tags: php, mongodb

I have an application using Vue + Laravel and I am using **mysql** database. Now, I need to use **mongodb** database too.

So, here is my live mongodb database table (projects) and collection (product_1, product_2 etc...)

Like this:

https://prnt.sc/D08akhBur6z4

Now, I want to get all the collection. To do that I have created Model called `Import`

**Import.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class Import extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'projects';
}
```

and created a controller called ImportController.php.

**ImportController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Import;

class ImportController extends Controller
{   
    public function show_import () {
        $all_import = Import::all();
        return response()->json( $all_import, 200);    
    }
}
```

**.env file**

```
MONGO_DB_HOST=107.200.220.71
MONGO_DB_PORT=57019
MONGO_DB_DATABASE=projects
MONGO_DB_USERNAME=marketplus_pr
MONGO_DB_PASSWORD="my-password"
```

**database.php**

```
'mongodb'   =>  [
    'driver'    =>  'mongodb',
    'dsn' => 'mongodb+srv://marketplus_pr:my-password@107.200.220.71/projects?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
    'database'  =>  'projects'
],
```

**Now using this api route call:**

http://localhost:3000/api/projects/import/show-import/343-3-3-3-3

I am getting this message:

```
{"success":false}
```

But Its should give me all the collection, right?

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: why? I am using msyql and as well as mongodb too

Comment: @OMiShah. I have updated:  Its should be this `Import::all();`right?

Comment: As there is no `Projects` model. There are only `Import` model I have created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248795/discussion-between-shibbir-and-omi-shah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is being intercepted by a different route declaration / controller. ([chat reference](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55374039#55374039)) Also, wrong collection name.

You should make a few changes in the api.php file:

Move this route declaration:

```
Route::get('projects/import/show-import/{token}', [App\Http\Controllers\ImportController::class, 'show_import'])->name('show_import');
```

just after:

```
Route::group([], function ($router) {
```

making it as:

```
Route::group([], function ($router) {

   Route::get('projects/import/show-import/{token}', 
      [App\Http\Controllers\ImportController::class, 'show_import'])- 
      >name('show_import');

    ...
}
```

*also, the `{token}` URL parameter makes not sense so you should remove it.*

and, change the collection name to `products_1` in the `Import.php` model file:

```
class Import extends Model
{
   protected $connection = 'mongodb';
   protected $collection = 'products_1'; // this should be collection name and not the database name: products_1, products_2, etc.
   ...
}
```

Comment: @Shibbir a different route was intercepting the request due to precedence.

Answer (score 0):

By default mongodb runs on port 27017, but looking at your connection string you are not sending that port to the connection. In case you are sure you are running mongodb in that port your connection string needs to be:

```
mongodb+srv://marketplus_pr:my-password@107.200.220.71:57019?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

On the other hand if you are not set the port at the moment of running your mongodb instance, this would be 27017, so the connection string will be:

```
mongodb+srv://marketplus_pr:my-password@107.200.220.71:27017?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am still getting that error message. \