# Laravel / Mongdb - DB::collection() is not working

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I am following this Laravel/Mongodb package: https://github.com/jenssegers/. Here if you go to this section https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#basic-usage-2 you can see that they are using `DB::collection()` method and passed the collection name to that.

Now, in my controller, I am trying to do this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Import;
use App\Models\Projects;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Collection;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder;

class ImportController extends Controller
{   

    public function get_all_products() {

        // Predefined key
        $predefined_keys = [ 'image_link', 'title', 'price', 'brand', 'link' ];

        // Get all the products
        //$get_products = Import::paginate(10);

        $get_products = DB::collection('products_1')->get();


        return response()->json($get_products, 200);    
    }
}
```

but I don't get any result. Can you tell me what I am missing here?

**My goal is to set the collectioin name directly in this controller not in Model.**

**Update:**.

**Here is my Import Mode:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class Import extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'products_46';

    // protected $table = 'projects';

}
```

Comment: is'nt collection equivalant to table?

Comment: @Hefaz I am not sure about that. I

Comment: I need to use mongodb collection name. I don't think table will work.

Comment: based on the documentation, i think it is. now do you have a table named products_1?

Comment: No, As I said I am using mongodb connection to get data from the collection not table.

Comment: OK. what is the output of `$get_products = DB::collection('products_1')->get();` ?

Comment: I got htis error: `message": "Method Illuminate\\Database\\MySqlConnection::collection does not exist.",`

Comment: Can you check that mongto db package and tell me which collection it is reffering?

Comment: Can you please show us the products model?

Comment: I have added to my question. Basically its `Import` model.

Comment: One last question, are you sure your connection configuations are working properly?

Comment: Using this `$get_products = Import::paginate(10);` I can get the data successfully.

Comment: try this: `$get_products= DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('products_46')->get();` and show output.

Comment: Let me try it now.

Comment: No, it's not working. I can't get any data.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with how you have configured this project.

From the documentation that you linked:

> When using MongoDB connections, Laravel will automatically provide you with the corresponding MongoDB objects.

Yet [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74119932/laravel-mongdb-dbcollection-is-not-working#comment130865896_74119932) you report that `DB::collection('products_1')->get();` results in:

```
message": "Method Illuminate\\Database\\MySqlConnection::collection does not exist."
```

This error message is referencing *MySQL* rather than MongoDB. It seems you are using MySQL for other portions of your application per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74067133/laravel-mongodb-cant-get-the-data-from-the-collection).

In any case, I think the answer is to be sure to [load the packages appropriately](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#laravel) (and perhaps also to disambiguate between namespaces if `DB` is separately defined in `Illuminate\Support\Facades` and is in scope for this portion of the code).

Comment: Can you check this please: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/blob/master/tests/CollectionTest.php? they are using `
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Collection;`

Comment: I'm not sure that changes my advice in any way? It is clear that Laravel provides MongoDB functionality. The problem seems to be that in your current configuration there is ambiguity with `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` and the wrong components are registered and being used by the code you've provided.

Comment: Well, can you tell me right components I should use?